# Parsing HTML page using bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a web HTML page and im trying to parse it.

Source ::

```
<tr class="active0"><td class=ac><a name="redis/172.29.219.17"></a><a class=lfsb href="#redis/172.29.219.17">172.29.219.17</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>-</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>-</td><td><u>0<div class=tips><table class=det><tr><th>Cum. sessions:</th><td>0</td></tr><tr><th colspan=3>Avg over last 1024 success. conn.</th></tr><tr><th>- Queue time:</th><td>0</td><td>ms</td></tr><tr><th>- Connect time:</th><td>0</td><td>ms</td></tr><tr><th>- Total time:</th><td>0</td><td>ms</td></tr></table></div></u></td><td>0</td><td>?</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td><u>0<div class=tips>Connection resets during transfers: 0 client, 0 server</div></u></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td class=ac>17h12m DOWN</td><td class=ac><u> L7TOUT in 1001ms<div class=tips>Layer7 timeout:  at step 6 of tcp-check (expect string &#39;role:master&#39;)</div></u></td><td class=ac>1</td><td class=ac>Y</td><td class=ac>-</td><td><u>1<div class=tips>Failed Health Checks</div></u></td><td>1</td><td>17h12m</td><td class=ac>-</td></tr>
<tr class="backend"><td class=ac><a name="redis/Backend"></a><a class=lfsb href="#redis/Backend">Backend</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>1</td><td>24</td><td></td><td>29</td><td>41</td><td>200</td><td><u>5<span class="rls">4</span>033<div class=tips><table class=det><tr><th>Cum. sessions:</th><td>5<span class="rls">4</span>033</td></tr><tr><th>- Queue time:</th><td>0</td><td>ms</td></tr><tr><th>- Connect time:</th><td>0</td><td>ms</td></tr><tr><th>- Total time:</th><td><span class="rls">6</span>094</td><td>ms</td></tr></table></div></u></td><td>5<span class="rls">4</span>033</td><td>1s</td><td><span class="rls">4</span>89<span class="rls">1</span>000</td><td>1<span class="rls">8</span>11<span class="rls">6</span>385<div class=tips>compression: in=0 out=0 bypassed=0 savings=0%</div></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>0</td><td><u>0<div class=tips>Connection resets during transfers: 54004 client, 0 server</div></u></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td class=ac>17h12m UP</td><td class=ac>&nbsp;</td><td class=ac>1</td><td class=ac>1</td><td class=ac>0</td><td class=ac>&nbsp;</td><td>0</td><td>0s</td><td></td></tr></table><p>
```

What I want is ::

```
172.29.219.17 L7TOUT in 1001ms
```

So what Im trying right now is ::

```
grep redis index.html  | grep 'a name=\"redis\/[0-9]*.*\"'
```

to extract the IP address.

But the regex doesnt seem to look at pick out the only the first row and returns both the rows whereas the IP is only in row 1.

Ive doublecheck the regex im using but it doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you use a proper `HTML` parser instead of `grep`?

Comment: you are asking for trouble. take a look at python module `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: if you must use regex change [0-9]* to [0-9]+ which ensures there is at least one number (ie. an IP address)

Answer (score 4):

Using `xpath` expressions in `xmllint` with its built-in `HTML` parser would produce an output as

```
ipAddr=$(xmllint --html --xpath "string(//tr[1]/td[1])" html)
172.29.219.17
```

and for the time out value prediction, I did a manual calculation of the number of the `td` row containing the value, which turned out to be `24`

```
xmllint --html --xpath "string(//tr[1]/td[24]/u[1])" html
```

produces an output as

```
         L7TOUT in 1001ms
         Layer7 timeout:  at step 6 of tcp-check (expect string 'role:master')
```

removing the whitespaces and extracting out only the needed parts with `Awk` as

```
xmllint --html --xpath "string(//tr[1]/td[24]/u[1])" html | awk 'NF && /L7TOUT/{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"",$0); print}'
L7TOUT in 1001ms
```

put in a variable as

```
timeOut=$(xmllint --html --xpath "string(//tr[1]/td[24]/u[1])" html | awk 'NF && /L7TOUT/{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"",$0); print}'
```

Now you can print both the values together as

```
echo "${ipAddr} ${timeOut}"
172.29.219.17 L7TOUT in 1001ms
```

version details,

```
xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20902
```

Also there is an incorrect tag in your `HTML` input file `</table>` at the end just before `<p>` which `xmllint` reports as

> htmlfile:147: HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : table

remove the line before further testing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of command line tools that will help you parse different formats via bash; bash is extremely powerful and useful.

- JSON utilize [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- XML/HTML utilize [xq](https://github.com/sibprogrammer/xq)
- YAML utilize [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)
- CSS utilize [bashcss](https://github.com/palmerlovett/bashcss)

  - I have tested all the other tools, comment on this one

If the code starts getting truly complex you might consider the naive answer below as coding languages with class support will assit.

### naive - Old Answer

Parsing complex formats like JSON, XML, HTML, CSS, YAML, ...ETC is extremely difficult in bash and likely error prone.  Because of this I recommend one of the following:

- PHP
- RUBY
- PYTHON
- GOLANG

because these languages are cross platform and have parsers for all the above listed formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse HTML with regexes, then you have to make **assumptions** about the HTML formatting. E.g. you assume here that the `a` tag and its `name` attribute is on the same line. However, this is perfect HTML too:

```
<a
    name="redis/172.29.219.17">
    Some text
</a>
```

Anyway, let's sole the problem assuming that the `a` tags are on one line and the `name` is the first attribute. This is what I could come up with:

```
  sed 's/\(<a name="redis\)/\n\1/g' index.html | grep '^<a name="redis\/[0-9.]\+"' | sed -e 's/^<a name="redis\///g' -e 's/".*//g'
```

Explanation:

- The first `sed` command makes sure that all `<a name="redis` text goes to a separate line.
- Then the `grep` keeps only those lines that start with `

  The last sed contains two expressions:

  - The first expressions removes the leading `<a name="redis/` text
  - The last expression removes everything that comes after the closing `"`